# Запуск функции внешней библиотеки из приложения microsoft access

Tags: c#, access

Добрый день.
Есть таблица в Microsoft access с полями

```
Слово
Перевод
Source_Sound
Source_Picture
Language
```

Я хочу вносить слово (ну например пусть и перевод тоже) и хочу, что б во время добавления слова запустился триггер и передал программке/библиотеке слово.Она взяла это, приняв язык и обратилась к гуглу за озвучкой этого слова, скачала mp3 и назвала его, передала название mp3 в базу и там сохранилась ссылка. Точно так-же и с первой попавшейся картинкой по данному слову.

Подскажите или направьте, пожалуйста, куда смотреть.
Думаю библиотеку на c# писать.  Или может средствами Visual Basik как-то можно.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

запросы акцесса позволяют вызывать определенные в нем же функции. а уж из вба  можно вызвать вашу библиотеку, если она СОМ-совместима.